# Spring-like PostProcessor Hook on Dynamically Registered Third-Party Bean

Tags: java, spring, grpc, spring-bean, grpc-java

What Spring Framework hook do I use on dynamically registered third-party beans?

I have a [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html#postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry-org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry-) that I am using to dynamically classpath-scan and instantiate multiple third-party beans (gRPC `AbstractStub` instances). I need to register [`ClientInterceptors`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/AbstractStub.html#withInterceptors-io.grpc.ClientInterceptor...-) on the stub so that the augmented `AbstractStub` is ready for application processing. I use dynamically-created `*Stub` `@Beans` to eliminate all the `@Bean` boilerplate and ensure consistent channel configurations.

#### Constraints

- The `AbstractStub` implementations are gRPC-generated classes. My classes extend `AbstractStub`.
- The preferred static factory method to use is the [`builder(Channel)`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/AbstractStub.html#build-io.grpc.Channel-io.grpc.CallOptions-) method; this is what is used when manually boilerplating `@Bean` declarations.
- Each stub requires a `Channel` as a dependency. There are multiple `Channel` `@Beans`.

## Attempts

I tried three approaches:

### Approach 1: `BeanDefinitionBuilder`+ `Supplier` Function

[`BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(Class, Supplier)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder.html#genericBeanDefinition-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Supplier-) did not allow injecting the `Channel` dependency.

```
void registerBeanDefintion(final Class<S> clazz, final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    Supplier<S> stubSupplier = () -> {
        clazz.getConstructor({Channel.class});
        return BeanUtils.instantiateClass(constructor, null); // fails here; no Channel
    }
    BeanDefinitionBuilder builder =
        BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(clazz, stubSupplier);
    builder.addDependsOn(MANAGED_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME);
    builder.addConstructorArgReference(MANAGED_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME);
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(clazz.getName(), builder.getBeanDefinition());
```

### Approach 2: `BeanDefinitionBuilder` with `CallOption` hooks

Unable to register a `ClientInterceptor` on a BeanDefinition.

```
void registerBeanDefintion(final Class<S> clazz, final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    builder.addDependsOn(MANAGED_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME);
    builder.addConstructorArgReference(MANAGED_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME);
    CallOptions callOptions = CallOptions.DEFAULT;
    // no hook in CallOptions to register ClientInterceptor
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(clazz.getName(), builder.getBeanDefinition());
```

### Approach 3: `postProcessBeanFactory()`

`postProcessBeanFactory` doesn't operate on instantiated beans, so dependencies are not pre-resolved.

```
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) throws BeansException {
    Iterator<String> iterator = configurableListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String beanName = iterator.next();
        if (beanName.endsWith("Stub")) {
            AbstractStub stub = (AbstractStub) configurableListableBeanFactory.getBean(beanName); //fails
            stub.withInterceptors(newClientInterceptor()); // never gets executed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the if block, you have   BeanDefinition beanDefinition =  and it's not assigned to anything? is that a pasto

Comment: @zee yes, copy pasta. updated, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was over-complicating it a bit since I had some separate modules: The solution is to use a simple `BeanPostProcessor` and invoke `withInterceptors()` for only the `AbstractStub` instances:

```
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof AbstractStub) {
            AbstractStub stub = (AbstractStub) bean;
            log.debug("modify bean '{}': add timeout client interceptor", beanName);
            ClientInterceptor timeoutClientInterceptor = this.newTimeoutClientInterceptor(stub);
            AbstractStub result = stub.withInterceptors(timeoutClientInterceptor);
            return result;
        }
        return bean;
    }

    ClientInterceptor newTimeoutClientInterceptor(final AbstractStub stub) {
        final Deadline deadline = this.getDeadlineTimeout(stub);
        return new ClientInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
                final ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> clientCall = next.newCall(method, callOptions.withDeadline(deadline));
                return new ClientInterceptors.CheckedForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(clientCall) {
                    @Override
                    protected void checkedStart(Listener<RespT> listener, Metadata metadata) {
                        log.debug("execute call with deadline {}", deadline);
                        delegate().start(listener, metadata);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
```